# FirebaseUi-web Verify button not working on Safari

Tags: firebase, safari, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Using FirebaseUI on a web and the Verify Button on a Phone Verification is not working on Safari - Iphone and Mac.
On Chrome works.

Comment: What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4)